# Importing importing gmail contacts to my page?

Tags: php, import, gmail, contacts

I am trying to import the gmail contacts to my page but there is an error called Curl function is undefined ..How to solve this problem ...
And Is there any way to import the yahoo mail contacts?

Comment: You will need to provide some more details (code maybe?) for anyone to understand the problem.

Comment: you can use this useful link all code in this link http://openinviter.com/download.php

Comment: You can use this link http://25labs.com/import-gmail-or-google-contacts-using-google-contacts-data-api-3-0-and-oauth-2-0-in-php/#_=_ its the latest and best way others are depricated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using PHP. Seems like `curl` is not installed. Take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php or contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

1. open php.ini
2. Search for ‘extension=php_curl.dll’.
   If not found add it to ‘Dynamic Extensions’ section.
   If found, uncomment the statement.
3. Then restart Apache if on localhost.

then you should not this error.